# how to give space between class "input-group" icon and textbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can i give space between textbox and icon:-

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the corresponding CSS for the classes or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @Syfer i have not created any css Please help me or give me hint so i can do myself.

Comment: If you have the HTML then you should have the CSS with it? You can follow the instructions given below i suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin-right`

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="margin-right: 10px">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
</div>
```

Here is the working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" style="margin-right: 10px">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```